# Result.data working in local and fails on Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

When I directly return result it adds a blank {} by its own in response json.
    but when i do `result.data` then it do not add that blank {}.
    but `result.data` do not work in server and raise exception.

```py
data = MasterInventoryBatch.query.filter_by(party_id=party_id).all()
        result = inventorysbatch_schema.dump(data)
return {
    "genericResponse": generic_response(responsecode.GET_BATCH_SUCCESS,
                                        "True",
                                        responsemessage.GET_BATCH_SUCCESS),
    "inventory": result
}
```

**ACTUAL RESULT**

```py
{
    "genericResponse": {
        "apiStatusMessage": "GET_BATCH_SUCCESS",
        "apiSuccessStatus": "True",
        "code": 16002,
        "newToken": "null",
        "newTokenGenerated": "false"
    },
    "inventory": [
        [
            {},{},{},{},....
        ],
        {}
    ]
}
```

**EXPECTED RESULT** 
ACTUAL RESULT

```py
{
    "genericResponse": {
        "apiStatusMessage": "GET_BATCH_SUCCESS",
        "apiSuccessStatus": "True",
        "code": 16002,
        "newToken": "null",
        "newTokenGenerated": "false"
    },
    "inventory":[
            {},{},{},{},....
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your code is as follows

```
data = MasterInventoryBatch.query.filter_by(party_id=party_id).all()
result = inventorysbatch_schema.dump(data)
response = generic_response(responsecode.GET_BATCH_SUCCESS, "True", responsemessage.GET_BATCH_SUCCESS)
return {
    "genericResponse": response,
    "inventory": result,
}
```

If I understand correctly,

- while returning `result` you are getting `[[{},{},{},{},....],{}]`
- while returning `result.data` is throwing error in server

can you try returning the response using `jsonify()` as follows

```
return jsonify({
    "genericResponse": response,
    "inventory": result,
})
```